# JSF 2.0 commandLink: how to pass a the page number as a parameter in the browser?

Tags: jsf-2

I want to pass the number each of clicks page of search results from tables in the browser with JSF commandLink Tag. But it does not work. I always get the following URL: http://localhost:myport/kundenVerwaltungWebClient/searchPerson.jsf

The URL in the browser should look something like this:
http://localhost:myport/kundenVerwaltungWebClient/searchPerson.jsf?pageNum=6

Here is the view (searchPerson.xhtml):

```
... <!-- The paging links -->
                                    <t:dataList value="#{controller.pages}" var="page">
                                        <h:commandLink value="#{page}" actionListener="#{controller.page}"
                                            rendered="#{page != controller.currentPage}" >
                                            <f:param name="pageNum" value="#{page}" />
                                        </h:commandLink>
                                        <b><h:outputText value="#{page}" escape="false"
                                            rendered="#{page == controller.currentPage}" /></b>
                                    </t:dataList> ...
```

Here is the managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean @SessionScoped public class Controller { private String pageNum; ... //Getter and Setter }
```

Can someone please tell me what I do wrong here?

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `<h:commandLink>` sends a POST request, but you apparently want to send a GET request. You need to use `<h:link>` instead of `<h:commandLink>` if you want to send a GET request.

```
<h:link value="#{page}" rendered="#{page != controller.currentPage}" >
    <f:param name="pageNum" value="#{page}" />
</h:link>
```

*(this doesn't require a `<h:form>` by the way, so you can safely remove it if you don't have any other command links/buttons in the view)*

To replace the `actionListener` job, put this in the top of your view:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="pageNum" value="#{controller.currentPage}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{controller.page}" />
</f:metadata>
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.
It worked. I want to do it now with paging buttons in the same view. How can I do that?Do you have an example for this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just the same way? Or if the functional requirement is really different (doesn't seem to be though), ask a new question.

Comment: Yes, i want to do it exactly the same way. See one of the buttons like this: <h:commandButton value="first" action="#{controller.pageFirst}" disabled="#{controller.pagedDataTable.first == 0}" />
How do I modify it?